# Add a distinct number with a foreign Key in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, distinct, recursive-query

This is our table

[image]

I made a recursive function in my code that I wouldn't have duplicate entries, but as you see there is a slip-up, does anyone know what I can do to have a unique entry for the "todaysOrder" if there are 2 devices that order at the exact time

Comment: where is your recursive function code?

Comment: Why recursion? Ask database what you need. There is a DISTINCT selector.

Comment: The problem comes in when 2 devices places an order at the same time then they have the same today order. We get the last order number with "ORDER BY ASC" and then plus 1 and add it, but the problem is when 2 devices do it at the same time